# Calling a function a nested state object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a fetch request to receive all my **json** data and store it in my current state, afterwards I want to call a function that will change the content of one of the nested json objects inside of an array.

I've looked at similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305920/calling-a-javascript-function-from-a-nested-objects-function-fails) but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the structure of my received json data:

```
[
   {
      "id":"George",
      "top":[
         {
            "performance":4289000,
            "day":"Sunday",
            "penalties":"none"
         },
         {
            "performance":4259000,
            "day":"Saturday",
            "penalties":"two"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"Maya",
      "top":[
         {
            "performance":4139000,
            "day":"Monday",
            "penalties":"none"
         },
         {
            "performance":4439000,
            "day":"Sunday",
            "penalties":"one"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

how can I perform a function on the **performance** object of the array **top** and pass it to the full state? For an example, how can I call a function for transforming milliseconds to a duration on this nested object?

Here is my function for changing time duration:

```
function parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime(milliseconds) {
    //Get hours from milliseconds
    var hours = milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60);
    var absoluteHours = Math.floor(hours);
    var h = absoluteHours > 9 ? absoluteHours : '0' + absoluteHours;
    //Get remainder from hours and convert to minutes
    var minutes = (hours - absoluteHours) * 60;
    var absoluteMinutes = Math.floor(minutes);
    var m = absoluteMinutes > 9 ? absoluteMinutes : '0' + absoluteMinutes;
    //Get remainder from minutes and convert to seconds
    var seconds = (minutes - absoluteMinutes) * 60;
    var absoluteSeconds = Math.floor(seconds);
    var s = absoluteSeconds > 9 ? absoluteSeconds : '0' + absoluteSeconds;
    return h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}
```

Question:

> How can I apply the function **parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime** to the **performance** object inside the **top** array and set it to **this.state** fore I render it to the html page?

Comment: if the parsed `performance` value is only for presentational purposes you could call the `parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime` in the render. Like a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rule we shouldn't mutate the state.

Therefore, in the cause you have to update the nested state `performance` key:

1. First you have to loop over the current state data, in order to create a **new** copy of the array.
2. Secondly, you can overwrite the `performance` key, applying `parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime` function.
3. Finally, having the new state, you can update your component state, using the data from `newState` constant (from the example below).

**Example** (*how to construct the new array, without mutations*):

```js
// Credits to @Tholle, for refactoring the below function.
const parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime = duration => {
  let seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60);
  let minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
  let hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

const state = [{
    "id": "George",
    "top": [{
      "performance": 4289000,
      "day": "Sunday",
      "penalties": "none"
    }, {
      "performance": 4259000,
      "day": "Saturday",
      "penalties": "two"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "Maya",
    "top": [{
      "performance": 4139000,
      "day": "Monday",
      "penalties": "none"
    }, {
      "performance": 4439000,
      "day": "Sunday",
      "penalties": "one"
    }]
  }
]

const newState = state.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  top: item.top.map(top => ({
    ...top,
    performance: parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime(top.performance)
  }))
}))

console.log(newState)
```

If you have questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hey Jodan, thanks for the assistance so far. I'm having issues fitting this inside my code since I am using a **fetch request**, can you help me out with that by any chance? Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kL2zvdma/)

Comment: Hey, I've applied the way I've constructed the `newState` in my answer. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jordan_enev/4z1k3786/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I am getting **error!  result.map is not a function** but I will figure this out on my own. Can I ask you a favor? Can you suggest any good reads on react that go beyond the basic tutorials? Thank you a lot for the assistance, I mean it.

Comment: Hm .. The fiddle I've provided you works and doesn't return an error. If the answer helped you, please consider voting / accepting it. About React resources - when I started with React, I began with understanding the React Main Concepts and Principles (from the Documentation) and after that I completed a React Udemy course.

Answer (score 1):

You can process the data before you put it in state by looping over all the elements in the array and all the elements in the nested `top` arrays and overwrite `performance` with the result of a call to `parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime`.

**Example**

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "George",
    top: [
      {
        performance: 4289000,
        day: "Sunday",
        penalties: "none"
      },
      {
        performance: 4259000,
        day: "Saturday",
        penalties: "two"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "Maya",
    top: [
      {
        performance: 4139000,
        day: "Monday",
        penalties: "none"
      },
      {
        performance: 4439000,
        day: "Sunday",
        penalties: "one"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function getData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(data);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime(duration) {
  let seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60);
  let minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
  let hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    getData().then(data => {
      data.forEach(item => {
        item.top.forEach(obj => {
          obj.performance = parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime(obj.performance);
        });
      });

      this.setState({ data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    if (data === null) {
      return null;
    }
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: yes this works with static data place inside the react file but I am trying to do it with a **fetch request**. Also when I tried to implement the code, I received an error on **getData()** not defined. Would an already created fiddle make this easier? [Here's a link](https://jsfiddle.net/kL2zvdma/)

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard `getData` is just an example since I don't have access to you API. I used it to demonstrate what to do when you get the data asynchronously. Try to map the `componentDidMount` in my answer to your own API logic.

Answer (score 0):

if the parsed `performance` value is only for presentational purposes you could call the `parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime` in `render` - Like a `filter`.

```js
// simplified single data object.
const data = {
  "id": "George",
  "top": [{
    "performance": 4289000,
    "day": "Sunday",
    "penalties": "none"
  }, {
    "performance": 4259000,
    "day": "Saturday",
    "penalties": "two"
  }]
}

const parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime = milliseconds => {
  //Get hours from milliseconds
  let hours = milliseconds / (1000*60*60);
  let absoluteHours = Math.floor(hours);
  let h = absoluteHours > 9 ? absoluteHours : '0' + absoluteHours;
  //Get remainder from hours and convert to minutes
  let minutes = (hours - absoluteHours) * 60;
  let absoluteMinutes = Math.floor(minutes);
  let m = absoluteMinutes > 9 ? absoluteMinutes : '0' +  absoluteMinutes;
  //Get remainder from minutes and convert to seconds
  let seconds = (minutes - absoluteMinutes) * 60;
  let absoluteSeconds = Math.floor(seconds);
  let s = absoluteSeconds > 9 ? absoluteSeconds : '0' + absoluteSeconds;
  return h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}

// example render function
render () {
  return (
    data.top.map(t => (
      <p>{parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime(t.performance)}</p>
    ))
  )
}
```